# Hello, I want to create a modal popup window using bootstrap but it (the pop up) is not coming up. I'm just wondering if I missed something

Tags: bootstrap-modal

×

> close
>               
>               
>                  Subscribe to our Mailing List
>
> Simply Enter your name and email! As a thank you for joining us, we're going to give you one of our best-selling courses, *for free!*

```
          <form class="form-inline" role="form">
           <div class="form-group ">
             <label class="sr-only" for="subscribe-name">Your first name</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subscribe-name" placeholder="Your first name">
            </div><!-- form group -->
           <div class="form-group ">
            <label class="sr-only" for="subscribe-email">and your email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subscribe-email" placeholder="and your email">
          </div><!-- form group -->
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Subscribe">
          </form>
        </form>

        <hr>

        <p><small>By providing your email you consent to receiving occasional promotional emails &amp; newsletters. <br>No spam. Just good stuff. We respect your privacy &amp; you may unsubscribe at any time.</small></p>

        </div><!-- modal body -->

      </div>
      <!-- modal header -->
    </div>
    <!-- modal content-->
  </div>
  <!-- modal dialog -->
</div>
<!-- modal-->
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? I don't see a modal anywhere in this html. Also you closed the form twice.

Comment: I was trying to add that , sorry

Comment: <!-- BOOTSTRAP CORE JAVASCRIPT
        placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster!
    =======================================================================================================-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: Please edit the post and please don't put code in the comment like that.

Comment: Apologies again, I was just editing the post. Please let me know if you see the javascript below.

Comment: Nope, I don't see any edits.